# How to import Oracle SQL Developer export dates using SQLPlus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I export data in Oracle SQL Developer v17.2 using Tools > Database Export ... . This gives me .sql file with sql statements.

I then try to import it using SQLPlus v12.2. Oracle SQL Developer generates me insert statements where time is formatted like this: `to_timestamp('06.10.2021 12:30:22,593000000','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF')`. These run fine when I run them using Oracle SQL Developer. But when I use SQLPlus I get error:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Is there way to make export that works with SQLPlus?

I know there is DBA view in Oracle SQL Developer but it says I don't have DBA privileges therefore I am looking to work with options that I have.

Comment: RRRR? Isn't that mean to be YYYY? (Is a non-Oracle guy wondering.)

Comment: @jarlh - doesn't really matter if a 4-digit year is provided. If a 2-digit year was provided then RRRR would treat 22 as 2022, while YYYY would treat is as 0022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL Developer and SQL*Plus sessions are set up differently; probably different locales, but the relevant part here is the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` setting in each environment, which is usually inherited form the territory.

Your `to_date()` format model uses `X` for the 'local radix character'. In SQL Developer that is a comma; in SQL*Plus it appears to be a period.

If you don't want to touch the statements, you can change your SQL*Plus session to match:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ef7acc27a2696b7fef565d98bae83dbf) showing the problem and fix.